# Adding and delete item into listview from array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, listview

I wish to add and delete items into listview from array, it is similar with shopping cart but i am using listview to do it.

I have tried to use append() but it will double add the items and the delete function is not working

```
$('#deleteme').on('tap', function () {

    console.log('delete button is tapped')
    $(this).parent().remove();
    $('#cartlist').listview('refresh');});

  $("#Addtocart").click(function () {
    console.log("addtocart button is tapped");

    var add = "";
    var title = arr[gindex].title;
    var price = arr[gindex].price;

    var Oprice = arr[gindex].Oprice;
    var img = arr[gindex].imgSmall;
    var Expiry = arr[gindex].Expiry;

    add = add + "<li><a class='ui-icon-delete' id='deteleme'>
     <img src=img/"
     + img + "><h3>" + title + "</h3><p><b>" + price + '</b><br>'
     + '<strike>' + Oprice + '</strike>' + '<br>' + "Expiry: " + Expiry 
     + "</p></a></li>";

    $('#cartlist').append(add);
    console.log("item is added");

    $('#cartlist').listview('refresh');
    console.log(add);});
```

I expect to add the item one by one and i can delete whatever item I want

Answer (score 0):

You add li with id `deleteme` dynamically, you attach a click handler but the item doesn't exist. So, you need to use delegate

```
$('body').on('tap','#deleteme', function () {
...
})
```

better to use the closest `deleteme` parent instead of `$('body')` for the better performance